# Maven failure to find codehaus artifact org.codehaus:codehaus-parent

Tags: java, maven, groovy, repository

So codehaus shut down (over the weekend, apparently): https://www.codehaus.org/

Now it says here that "Maven: All repositories are mirrored into Central, and our Nexus is hosted by Sonatype".  If I am reading this correctly, this means that it should continue to work (and because Central is the default repository, I shouldn't even have any changes to make).

Yet I am having trouble with a Maven project that used to compile (before the shutdown), but now fails:

```
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:maven-plugin:2.9.1-01
Reason: Cannot find parent: org.codehaus:codehaus-parent for project: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:maven-plugin:2.9.1-01 for project org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:maven-plugin:2.9.1-01
```

Here's a trimmed-down version of my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hp</groupId>
    <artifactId>device-state-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>device-state-service</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <groovy-all.version>2.3.7</groovy-all.version>
        <spock-core.version>0.7-groovy-2.0</spock-core.version>
        <lombok.version>1.12.2</lombok.version>
...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy-all.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>dss</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <javaAgentClass>lombok.core.Agent</javaAgentClass>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.1-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.7-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
...
        </plugins>
    </build>    
        <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dss</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>deliverable</name>
                    <value>dss</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1-alpha-1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>rpm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            ...
                            <name>${deliverable}</name>
                            <projversion>${pom.version}</projversion>
                            <release>${BUILD_NUMBER}</release>
                            <description>Search: RPM package</description>
                            <mappings>
                                <mapping>
                                    <directory>${tomcatInstallationDir}</directory>
                                    <filemode>755</filemode>
                                    <username>tomcat</username>
                                    <groupname>tomcat</groupname>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>
                                            <location>../Tomcat/</location>
                                        </source>
                                    </sources>
                                </mapping>
                                <mapping>
                                    <directory>${tomcatInstallationDir}/webapps</directory>
                                    <filemode>755</filemode>
                                    <username>tomcat</username>
                                    <groupname>tomcat</groupname>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>
                                            <location>target/${deliverable}.war
                                            </location>
                                            <destination>${deliverable}.war</destination>
                                        </source>
                                    </sources>
                                </mapping>
                            </mappings>
                            <requires>
                                <require>palm-jre &gt;= 1.6.0_27-fcs</require>
                            </requires>
                            <prefix>${tomcatInstallationDir}</prefix>
                            <preinstallScriptlet>
                                <scriptFile>../PlatformEngine/rpm_scripts/pre_install.sh</scriptFile>
                                <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
                            </preinstallScriptlet>
                            <postinstallScriptlet>
                                <scriptFile>../PlatformEngine/rpm_scripts/post_install.sh</scriptFile>
                                <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
                            </postinstallScriptlet>
                            <preremoveScriptlet>
                                <scriptFile>../PlatformEngine/rpm_scripts/pre_uninstall.sh</scriptFile>
                                <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
                            </preremoveScriptlet>
                            <postremoveScriptlet>
                                <scriptFile>../PlatformEngine/rpm_scripts/post_uninstall.sh</scriptFile>
                                <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
                            </postremoveScriptlet>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Now, in my .m2 directory I find for the `groovy-all` project a pom/sha1, and a jar file.  But for `groovy-eclipse-compiler`, I see the pom/sha1, *but no jar file*.

Am I doing something wrong?  Did something in the Codehaus migration itself get screwed up somehow?  Or (worse) both?

Comment: What do you mean by : `and our Nexus is hosted by Sonatype`?

Comment: What version of Maven do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what "and our Nexus is hosted by Sonatype" means, I was quoting from codehaus' shutdown page.

Maven version is 2.2.1 - I think I'm hitting a bug in Maven that might be fixed in a newer version (where it treats HTML non-200 codes with error documents as if they were valid file contents), but I can't upgrade.

Comment: Codehaus actually does a 302 followed by a 503. The fault is clearly by maven here for me, but problem is problem. Manually installing the offending artifact could maybe help, I don't know if maven will still check then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven artifacts are in central for a long time already, there is no migration that could have been screwed up for those.

Since I am no maven expert I can give you only what I assume is the cause. Looking at the pom for version 2.9.1-01 of the [groovy-eclipse-compiler](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-compiler/2.9.1-01/groovy-eclipse-compiler-2.9.1-01.pom) I see

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus.org</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

ans my assumption is, that this will cause maven to look in that repository, which does not exist anymore. If that is true, then my suggestion for a solution would be to manually install the artifacts (they are all on maven central) or to use a different tool like gradle (though that might be out of scope for you) to do the build.

***EDIT:***
I have been told that you could change your settings.xml to fix repository configurations with a pattern like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus.org</id>
        <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/<some suburl></url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact for example might then work, but I have not tested this.

Comment: I did see that, but I don't think that can be it.  I manually added in a "repositories" section from another pom I have, and it attempted to resolve the dependency from these other repositories.  So the "repository" section in the artifact's pom.xml seems to be additive (in other words 'look in this repository in addition to any others defined in the real pom.xml').

Comment: Actually that might be the cause of the problem.  I am seeing in the logs it attempting to get the artifact.  If I curl the same URL, I get back a 302 Moved error page; Maven seems to not notice it's an error, thinks its corrupt, and then says it can't find the dependency.

Comment: How did you confirm that?

Comment: I ran maven with -X and it spits out a list of all the repositories it tried (and failed) to find the artifact in.  When I add new repositories to my 'repositories' section, they show up there.

Comment: Aha!  I think I have found something dispositive.  The 302 Gone message has been written to my .m2 repository as if it were the pom for the artifact that Maven says it cannot find.  Maven is apparently not smart enough to realize this isn't a real pom.

Comment: I guess that is because the page does not send a 404 or something like that and instead does a redirect

Comment: It's a combination of 3 things.

1)  As noted, groovy-eclipse-compiler specifies the codehaus repository.  I tried everything and no matter what, it always contacts this repo.  2) codehaus.org returns 302 Found and an HTML error document, instead of (say) 410 Gone or 403 Not Found. 3) Maven 2.2.1 doesn't detect the error, blithely saving the HTML to the local repo as if it were the pom.xml for the artifact.  You can find this corruption by rgrepping the Maven repo for DOCTYPE.

To fix this, I had to first delete my local maven repository, then blackhole repository.codehaus.org in /etc/hosts.

Comment: I already fixed it by blackholing the offending domain.  If it can't contact the server returning the 302, it moves on to a valid server returning real data, and there is no issue.

Comment: good, just wanted to add that to have other people see a possible other solution

Answer (score 0):

The artifact you are referencing to:

```
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:maven-plugin:2.9.1-01
```

if this isn't being found by your build than simply your configuration is wrong. Either network/proxy issues etc. (see your settings.xml) You can search this artifact in Maven central via: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.groovy%22%20AND%20a%3A%22groovy-eclipse-compiler%22

Apart from that adding supplemental repositories this does not help. Furthermore adding default's in a Maven pom like this:

```xml
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
```

does not make sense either, cause these are the defaults. What i stumbled over as well is that you are defining things like the encoding:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

First it is good to define the version of plugins like this (but you should use [uptodate versions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/)) but you should not define the encoding in every plugin. For such purposes a property exist:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

by using the above you don't need to give the encoding for every plugin, cause the plugins like [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#encoding), [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) etc. define a default.

A word about the [codehaus migration](http://www.codehaus.org). This means only the services they have offered for developers are shutting down but not the content which already is part for Maven central.

I would recommend to install a repository manager in your own infrastructure.