# oozie-4.2.0 fails during compilation

Tags: maven, oozie

While building oozie 4.2.0 on my macbookpron , I experienced this issue below.
I am using

1. Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9;
   2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
2. Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle
   Corporation
3. Apache oozie-4.2.0

   ```
   $ bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests

   ...
   Downloaded: https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-9.2y/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-9.2y.jar (66 KB at 34.8 KB/sec)
   [INFO] Unable to load parent project from a relative path: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
   [FATAL] Non-readable POM /Users/abd_adebiyi/sw/apache/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/docs/../../pom.xml: /Users/abd_adebiyi/sw/apache/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/docs/../../pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 
    for project  at /Users/abd_adebiyi/sw/apache/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/docs/../../pom.xml for project  at /Users/abd_adebiyi/sw/apache/oozie/oozie-4.2.0/docs/../../pom.xml
   [INFO] Parent project loaded from repository.
   Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml
   Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml
   Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml
   Downloading: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Reactor Summary:
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [ 33.457 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SUCCESS [ 28.037 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SUCCESS [ 10.853 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SUCCESS [  1.538 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SUCCESS [04:58 min]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SUCCESS [  8.507 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SUCCESS [  7.247 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SUCCESS [  8.976 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ..................... SUCCESS [  8.926 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SUCCESS [  2.571 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SUCCESS [ 13.693 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ...................... SUCCESS [ 20.181 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SUCCESS [ 30.188 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. FAILURE [  9.458 s]
   [INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
   [INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
   [INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
   [INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests ............. SKIPPED
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 08:04 min
   [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-04T23:52:57+01:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 339M/1028M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-6:site (default) on project oozie-docs: The site descriptor cannot be resolved from the repository: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:xml:site_en:16 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository.codehaus.org: unknown error
   [ERROR] org.apache:apache:xml:16
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
   [ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
   [ERROR] Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
   [ERROR] apache.snapshots.repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots, releases=true, snapshots=true),
   [ERROR] datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
   [ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true): Unknown host repository.codehaus.org: unknown error
   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
   [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-docs

   ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
   ```

   I will appreciate if anyone can advise what I should do. I need this bugger out of the way.

I opened JIRA 2415 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2415.The of release of ooze-4.2 on 2015-Jun-03  was a few days shy of codehause (http://www.codehaus.org/history/) end of days (2015-May-31)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven failure to find codehaus artifact org.codehaus:codehaus-parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314301/maven-failure-to-find-codehaus-artifact-org-codehauscodehaus-parent)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve it by editing the parent pom.xml file by removing the repository Codehaus repository

```
  <repository>
    <id>Codehaus repository</id>
    <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
```

I would like to know if there is a better way.

The codehause repository has been closed and hence the errors.

[EDIT: archive.org has an archive of repository.codehaus.org
at https://web.archive.org/web/20150505221755/http://repository.codehaus.org/org ]

Comment: Here, you are explicitly asking to read from this repository.If you remove it it will pick from maven central repository,if nothing is specified.

Comment: Thanks Naruto. The repository was aded by default with ooze-4.2. I guess it is a bug the Oozie developers community need to look into.

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.m2/settings.xml, add a mirror entry for codehaus. This avoids editing the parent POM.

Example:

```
...
  <mirror>
    <id>codehaus</id>
    <mirrorOf>Codehaus repository</mirrorOf>
    <name>Codehaus repository</name>
    <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url> <!-- Point to Maven central instead -->
  </mirror>
...
```